# how to draw a line graph using java with fixed X-Y axes

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, applet

There is data which is distributed in two columns. X axis ranges from 0 to 1 with step values as 0.1, 0.2, 0.3.... 0.9,1.0. and Y axis ranges from 0 to 1500 with step value of 100. 0,100,200....1500. Data is in following form:

Column 1  Column 2  Column 3
A             0.5      512
B             0.7      600
C             0.8     1200

A line graph needs to be plotted using java/jquery/javascript which will plot points A,B,C on the graph such that Column2 is the x coordinate and Column3 is Y coordinate.....

Comment: If you're looking for simple charts in JavaScript, c3js is a good option. c3js.org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What did you try?

Try JavaFx line chart:
https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/line-chart.htm

Comment: Im new to charts using java, so need suggestions from scratch

Comment: just follow the link and you will get a tutorial, for free! :-)